# How to display an icon next to a Select element without obscuring the arrow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to add a help-icon after inputs as described [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/). It looks fine for Input elements. I  tried to do the same for Select elements, but it screws up the down arrow of the Select as can be seen in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-t9wey)

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
  id="demo-simple-select-adornment"
  value={age}
  onChange={handleChange}
  endAdornment={
    <InputAdornment position="end">
      <HelpOutline />
    </InputAdornment>
  }
>
  <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this [issue thread](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17799) - this seems to be a known issue which they currently do not intend to fix.

However, you can also find this [quick and dirty fix](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17799#issuecomment-589678881) suggested there, and [here is how it can be applied to the example you provided in the sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8wp38).

**tl;dr**: you can override the select-icon style with a `position: "relative"`:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  },
  selectIcon: {
    position: "relative"
  }
}))

...

 <Select
    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
    id="demo-simple-select-adornment"
    value={age}
    onChange={handleChange}
    classes={{
       icon: classes.selectIcon //overriding the select-icon style
       }}
     endAdornment={
         <InputAdornment position="end">
            <HelpOutline />
          </InputAdornment>
          }
      >
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
  </Select>
```